# How to get a Map of the url query with Camel rest?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

How can I configure Camel to pass all URL query arguments to a Map in a bean method?

Given this example code

```
@ContextName("camelBean")
public class CamelTestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {       
        rest("/foo").description("Test api")
            .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
            .get("/stuff").description("get stuff")
                .param().name("key").type(RestParamType.query).description("The key parameter").dataType("string").endParam()
                .responseMessage().code(200).message("The stuff").endResponseMessage()
                .to("bean:camelBean?method=getStuff")
            ;
    }
}

@Named("camelBean")
public class CamelServiceBean {

    public String getStuff(Map<String, String> args) {
        return String.valueOf(args);
    }

}
```

When I access `<camelurl>/foo/stuff?key=asdasd`, I want `getStuff` to be called with a map containing `'key' => 'asdasd'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the map with @Headers

http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Headers.html

```
public String getStuff(@Headers Map<String, Object> args) {
    return String.valueOf(args);
}
```

args will have end up with [this map](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Message.html#getHeaders()).

See [the documentation for annotations](http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html)